# Why do we need at least four charges to verify Coulomb's Law?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

I'm reading Tamm's Electrodynamics, and came across a passage which seems very elementary, but confusing, since I've never paid attention to the empirical justification of associating a constant charge $q$ to an object:

[image]

But the fact that we need at least $4$ charges isn't clear to me. I would appreciate a thorough explanation, as well as possible alternatives of justifying associating a constant charge number $q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you had no idea what the equation for electric force looked like. At the very least it must depend symmetrically on the magnitude of the charges since $F_{12}$ must equal $F_{21}$. This gets rid of expression like
$F_{12} \propto q_1(q_1+q_2) $ but expressions like $F_{12}\propto (q_1+q_2 )^n \text{ or }F_{12}\propto q_1q_2 + k $ where $k$ is consant are still valid. So now we measure $F_{12}$ and then we bring a third charge and measure $F_{23}$ and consider $\frac{F_{12}}{F_{23}}$. Note that with these two measurements we could not distinguish between the two expression for forces: $F_{ij}\propto q_iq_j$ or $(q_i+q_j)^n \text{ or } \propto q_iq_j + k $. But now let's bring in a fourth charge and measure $F_{14} \text{ and } F_{43} $ to get the ratio $\frac{F_{14}}{F_{43}}$. We would notice something interesting: the two ratios measured were equal despite the fact that the first ratio we used the third charge and the second measurement we used a fourth charge. So this means that expression like $(q_i +q_j)^n \text{ or } \propto q_1q_2 + k $ can't be correct because we need a cancellation for the ratio $\frac{F_{ik}}{F_{jk}}$ i.e the ratio can't depend on the ${q_k}$. The only way this can happen is if $F_{ij} \propto q_iq_j $. After this we are done. All it took was four measurements. Now is $q$ constant that?This can be verified by doing the four measurements at different distances and times.